# Hubspot Page Performance Status 403: Forbidden

Tags: http-status-code-403, hubspot

Hubspot Report > Page Performance

When I "refresh page data" with my external website on Hubspot, I got this error.

```
-------------------------------------
Message

Uh-oh, it looks like we're having some trouble retrieving this page. Here's what your server told us:
Status 403: Forbidden
-------------------------------------
```

But when I visiting my website its perfectly working fine.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your htaccess. in wordpress website.

```
#TID Allow the HubSpot User Agent
BrowserMatchNoCase HubSpot hubspot
Allow from env=hubspot
#TID Allow the HubSpot User Agent
```